# Issues with Annyang speech recognition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, mamp

I am currently trying to create my own J.A.R.V.I.S system as a web app. So of course, like any good J.A.R.V.I.S system, it needs good speech recognition. I have done research trying to find a JavaScript speech recognition API that I can customize as much as I like, and have decided to use Annyang. (It's simple, and works well)

I spent some time playing around with it, and just when I thought I had got it working, I ran into a problem. It wasn't working when I tried to view the file locally, so I hosted it on my computer with MAMP to see if it worked. It came up with the dialog saying "localhost would like to access the microphone", but when I clicked allow, it reappeared. It kept reappearing and wouldn't go away until I clicked deny. I was using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/1.0.0/annyang.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (annyang) {
// Let's define our first command. First the text we expect, and then the function it     should call
var commands = {
'show tps report': function() {
  alert("hello");
}
};

// Initialize annyang with our commands
annyang.init(commands);

// Start listening. You can call this here, or attach this call to an event, button, etc.
annyang.start();
}
</script>
```

Which is the demo code they supplied on [their website](https://www.talater.com/annyang/).

If anyone can help me figure out why it is repeatedly asking to use my microphone when I click allow, then *thank you* in advance!

Cheers,
Fjpackard.

Comment: Thanks man, mine was not working and I jusr realized it only works if the file is on server :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/issues/53

Please read through the whole issue. You might need to setup HTTPS for it.

Comment: Thanks very much for fast response, this helped me greatly! :)

Comment: adding Https instead of http?

Comment: I tried https  for my site
that is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same situation, I got it resolved. There are 2 solutions to fix the issue.

1. Close all the other tabs which uses the microphone.
2. Recheck, in your annyang.js file

   ```
   abort: function () {
       autoRestart = false;
       if (isInitialized) {
           recognition.abort();
       }
   }
   ```

   Which, need to remove stop the activities of microphone from all the inactive tabs, and need to activate only for current tab.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt will reappear if there is no SSL for every time the Listening action starts.

If you have a valid SSL on a FQDN it will work, as long as you have setup the javascript correctly.

Right now it is prompting, as after you Allow it, it cycles through the preconfigured matches, and then starts over, and prompts again.

I have a working example in Bulgarian, if you want to look at: https://piperko.com